# Java Program: Where am I going wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

Problem: Write a program that reads a list of real numbers.  After the program ends it should print out only the unique numbers.  That is, only numbers that appear once in the list.  If there are more than 50 unique numbers on the list, then you should only print the first 50.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Hmwk {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input=new Scanner (new File ("input.txt"));
    int n = 0;
    final int MAX_SIZE = 50;
    double[] numbersArray = new double[MAX_SIZE];
    while (input.hasNextDouble() && n<MAX_SIZE){
        double in = input.nextDouble();
        if (!inList(in,numbersArray)){
            numbersArray[n]=in;
            n++;
        }
    }
    double[] uniqueArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbersArray, 0, n);
    printReport(uniqueArray);
}


public static boolean inList(double number, double[] list){
    for (double i : list)
        {
            if (Math.abs(i-number) <0.00000000001){
                return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}


public static void printReport(double[] list)
{
    System.out.println("The unique numbers were");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));

}


}
```

It's running well but I can't seem to figure out where my logic is going wrong. I'm running it against the input.txt of 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 0 and my output is

```
The unique numbers were
[5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

My roommate and I can't seem to pinpoint my problem. I THINK i've accounted for every mistake that could be made, but then again computers are better at doing what you tell them to do instead of what you want them to do. If anyone could pinpoint my problem and show me how to fix it i'd be forever grateful. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are you using that if-statement with < 0.000000000001 in inList to check if the number is in the list?

Comment: Mdewitt: did it to deal with integers-> doubles, professor told me to.

Comment: So what is the exact problem? The absence of `0.0`?

Comment: Tyler- they are all integers. such as 5 6 7 etc

Comment: The problem is numbers that appear more than once in input.txt are being added to numbers array.

Comment: All integers in this file

Comment: You are checking whether each number is in the list before you add it. So you'll always add the first instance of each number. You need to rethink your algorithm.

Comment: @user102817 By "print out only the unique numbers" do you mean you need to print out only the numbers that appear once in the file, or you need to print one of every character in the file? (i.e. in a file with {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2} do you need to print {3, 4} or {1, 2, 3, 4}?)

Comment: i were wondering do you have to use an array? since whenever you are talking about unique `Set` would be much better option :)

Comment: @mdl I think "The problem is numbers that appear more than once in input.txt are being added to numbers array." implies {3,4} is the expected output for {1,2,3,4,1,2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *adding numbers to the list once*, instead of *looking for the **unique** numbers*. That is the difference. (BTW: The reason why `0.0` is not in the output is because the array is full of zeros by default.)

Basically you should have this:

1. Read all the numbers in an array.
2. Run over every number in that list, and check if it is unique.
3. If so, add it to the final array.

Checking wether an element is unique can simply be done by counting the occurrences of that element in the entire list by looping over it again.

Comment: A number is not added to the array if the array already contains the given number (that's what `inList` is used for). So the array will only contain unique numbers (apart from 0).

Comment: I know, that is what I told him. Why all the downvotes? This is the correct answer. He wants to pick only the **unique** numbers. He doesn't want to make every number occur once in the final result.

Comment: @Njol the array will contain unique numbers, but it will not contain only numbers that were unique in the input. This answer fixes that problem.

Answer (score 2):

(only part of the problem, sorry. see the other answers for the rest)

The array is filled with zeroes when it is created, thus zero will always be `inList`. You could change that function to only check the values that were actually set by adding a parameter for the length of the list:

```
public static boolean inList(double number, double[] list, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (Math.abs(line[i] - number) < 0.00000000001)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

BTW: you could also use an `ArrayList<Double>` or `HashSet<Double>` which take care of the variable array size.

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem with 8 and 9 being output